# How can I restore the changed value of an ObservableCollection?

Tags: c#, list, observablecollection, xamdatagrid

I have an `ObservableCollection<T>` of a class.

```
class person
{
   string name;
   string age;
}
```

I also have one `List<T>`. I'm getting data from XML tags populating in the collection as well as list from the XML.

```
listVAR.add (new person(xml.name.value,xml.age.value));
collectionVAR(new person(xml.name.value,xml.age.value));
```

Now I modify the data in collection. There is a senario where I have to restore the old values, but when I add them, clearing the collection first, the old value is reflected. For example:

age changed from 35 to 45 in collection through an `XamDataGrid`. Now my list has the value 35.

```
collectionVAR.clear();

foreach(people item in listVAR)
{
    collectionVAR.add(item);
}
```

but here I see that value 35 not restored. Can anyone explain to me why?

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that only one copy of the `Person` class exists while this could be contained within two collections (main collection and the `ObservableCollection`).

So when you add items from the collection to `ObservableCollection`, **they will be pointing to the same objects.** So when you edit objects, they will be changed in both collections.

Solution is to clone the `Person` objects first and then add the clone to the `ObservableCollection`.